# How to transform a Kibana query to `elasticsearch_dsl` query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have a query

`GET index/_search`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "key1": "value"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "key2": "*match*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make the same call with `elasticsearch_dsl` package
I tried with

```
s = Search(index=index).query({
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "key1": "value"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "key2": "*match*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })
s.using(self.client).scan()
```

But the results are not same, am I missing something here

Is there a way to represent my query with `elasticsearch_dsl`
tried this, no results

```
s = Search(index=index).query('wildcard', key2='*match*').query('match', key1=value)
s.using(self.client).scan()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked for me

```
s = Search(index=index).query('match', key1=value)
                       .query('wildcard', key2='*match*')
                       .source(fields)
```

also, if key has `_` like `key_1` elastic search behaves differently and query matches results even which do not match your query. So try to choose your `key` which do not have underscores.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you forgot the stars in the query.

```
s = Search(index=index).query('wildcard', key='*match*').query('match', key=value)
```

Comment: sorry, I had starts in the query as well